# Place three edittext-widgets horizontally with same length

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

How do I best put three edittext on the same row in a linearlayout and let them have the same size? Is the solution to get the screenwidth and divide it by the number of edittext-widtegs?

In the following xml-code - the last edittext does not fit within the screenwidth.

Set the layout width in absoulute px will not be a good idea since the screen-size differ from phone to phone.

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number1_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number2_input2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number3_input3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want all the child views to be e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_width="0dp"`, and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to each of the `<EditText>` elements. See [the documentation on LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) for more about how to use `android:layout_weight`.